# Does runnable run() create a thread everytime I call it?

Tags: java

I wrote a class which I use like as follows:

```
EventWrapperBuilder.newWrapperBuilder().
            addSync(this::<some_method>).
            addSync(this::<some_method>).
            addSync(this::<some_method>).
            addAsync(() -> <some_method>, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).
            GET();
```

My code is the following:

```
private final List<EventWrapper> _wrappers = new ArrayList<>();

    public EventWrapperBuilder addSync(final Runnable task)
    {
        _wrappers.add(new EventWrapper(task, Duration.ZERO));
        return this;
    }

    public EventWrapperBuilder addAsync(final Runnable task, final Duration duration)
    {
        _wrappers.add(new EventWrapper(task, duration));
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return {@code List} of all {@code Future}
     */
    public List<Future<?>> GET()
    {
        final List<Future<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (final EventWrapper wrapper : getWrappers())
        {
            if (!wrapper.getDuration().isZero())
            {
                list.add(ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().scheduleEvent(wrapper.getTask(), wrapper.getDuration().toMillis()));
            }
            else
            {
                wrapper.getTask().run();
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    /**
     * @param builder
     * @return {@code EventWrapperBuilder}
     */
    public EventWrapperBuilder COMBINE(final EventWrapperBuilder builder)
    {
        _wrappers.addAll(builder.getWrappers());
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return {@code List} of all {@code EventWrapper}
     */
    public List<EventWrapper> getWrappers()
    {
        return _wrappers;
    }

    //@formatter:off
    private static record EventWrapper (Runnable getTask, Duration getDuration) {}
    //@formatter:on

    public static EventWrapperBuilder newWrapperBuilder()
    {
        return new EventWrapperBuilder();
    }
```

My question is: Do I create a new thread every time I execute this if it's instant i.e. the `EventWrappers` duration is zero?

I obviously know that the

```
list.add(ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().scheduleEvent(wrapper.getTask(), wrapper.getDuration().toMillis()));
```

creates a thread and execute it after the scheduled time but the

```
wrapper.getTask().run();
```

is real time without a thread right?
I don't want my code to create threads and therefore to be heavy when it executes `run()`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code and look at how many threads you have.

Comment: `Runnable.run()` *never* creates a new thread. Only `Thread.start()` does that.

Comment: Put a comment there. This is the kind of thing that is confusing to readers and that will be confusing to you in a couple of weeks. Doing something synchronous with a class that has async capabilites in a method where it also gets used the async way is something people will stumble about.

Comment: mindoverflow i didn't quite catch what you mean.

Comment: `Runnable` itself has nothing to do with threads, neither has `run()` from `Runnable`. The `Thread` class and classes like `Executor` do. They demand a `Runnable` from you, i.e. something that they can execute/run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, calling `run()` of the Runnable interface will not spawn a new thread.
On the other hand, when you wrap the Runnable with a Thread class and call `start()` then the JVM will spawn a new thread and execute the Runnable in it's context.

In your code, only the Async tasks will run in a separate thread since the Threadpool is managing their execution.

Comment: Thank you very much, so in terms of code the addSync will execute my methods as if i called them 1 by 1 normal? It's the same time in terms of execution in java?

Comment: yes, the run() method doesn't add anything. it's just like calling a normal method.
if this solves your question, please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, calling `run()` will execute the Runnable in the current thread, while calling `start()` will run the Runnable in the new thread.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run()
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()